# Deploy a Symfony project with GIT - Error: 'Does not appear to be a git repository and Could not read from remote repository'

Tags: git, symfony

I am currently trying to push my Symfony project thanks to GIT in my web server, the connection is done by ssh.

I first created a GIT project in the web server like this:

[Filezilla Configuration (link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57gQF.png)

Then I do these commands locally at the location of my Symfony project, first by doing a:

`git init`

Then come the connection with the branch of the site:

`git remote add live ssh://kasumi@ssh-kasumi.alwaysdata.net/var/git/symfony.git/`

Then adding all the files from my folder with:

`git add .`

Then:

`git commit -m "first deploiment"`

and to finish:

`git push live master`

And I get the following error:

```
fatal: '/var/git/symfony.git/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Here it connects well to my ssh since it asks me the password, I am sure to have the right password.

But it tells me that at this location that no GIT project is present it seems to me. Why then did I create it well in this space.

Maybe I put it wrong to indicate the tree?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

**EDIT : 
thank you very much for your answer I finally succeeded! I first create a git depot on github and then clone it directly in the ssh ( command : git clone ) of the site!**

Comment: try to clone in another folder your poject: `git clone ssh://kasumi@ssh-kasumi.alwaysdata.net/var/git/symfony.git`

Answer (score 0):

It will first check if you created the remote repository. So check if the repository was created on the web server

Comment: When you talk about remote repository do you talk about the repository git create with the command? :

`git init --bare`

if so yes my git files are in the location :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/57gQF.png